# Create a Power Apps where users can specifiy a schduled calls to custom connector

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp

We have created a custom connector, which do the following:-

1. Get all the accounts from external system.
2. Get the account details by passing the Ids returned from step one.

Then inside the Power App >> we need to loop through the returned account info , and do the following:-

1. If the account ID already exists inside a SharePoint list >> to update the account info.
2. If the account ID is new >> to add the account info inside SharePoint list.

This can be done, if the user will manually triggers calling the custom connector, by clicking a button for example. but i need to create a power Apps which will allow the user to do the following:-

1. The user will specify the Refresh rate in minutes. for example to do a call to the custom connector each 150 minutes.
2. Then power Apps will call the custom connector each 150 minutes without nay user intervention >> and updates the SharePoint list accordingly

so is this something we can build using Power Apps? In other word to build something similar to Scheduled Flow inside Power Automate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was trying to understand the question, turned out that what you're looking for is whether it's possible to create a scheduler/timer inside Power Apps that mimics Power Automate Scheduler Flow, where the user can close the app but the scheduler/timer keeps running in the background.

The straight answer is **NO**, because it is by design.

**Power Apps is designed as the foreground application**, the opposite of the background application, that (of course) runs only when the user opens the app and is destroyed when they close it.

When you put a Timer in the Power Apps with interval, the scheduler works as long as the app is running. A similar case is when you build a Windows Desktop app, a web application based on JavaScript, and then you put a timer in it.

In JavaScript, you use `setTimeout` function. In the Windows Desktop app, you use Timer. The same case for Power Apps, you also have Timer too.

[image]

This is where **Power Automate** comes into the picture. It works as the **background application**, the same case for Windows Service, where you can trigger based on:

1. a scheduler that **runs forever** (or as per scheduled) after it started regardless user closes the app or not.
2. based on a trigger, not only from Power Apps, but also when a record is created or modified.

[image]

Hope the explanation is clear enough.

Comment: i did not get your point why i need more than one Power Automate flows? Also how i can force Power Apps to keep running so it will call the flows according to the schdule?

Comment: Essentially all 4 flows runs together no matter what. In instance for the flow with scheduler of 90 minutes, the condition inside to check whether the Environment Variable is equal to 90 or not. If yes, then call the child flow where it updates Account ID. If not, it'll pass out and end just like that. You need that many flows, because scheduler flow can't run on conditional timing.

Comment: i am not sure i got your point ... inside Power Automate we can define a scheduled flow and define when it should run in the background.. so can we do the same using Power Apps?

Comment: Power Apps is just the UI to help users set the option whether they want to run at which intervals to update the Account ID. The logic is actually inside Power Automate. So, there's no logic/code where you trigger the flow from Power Apps. Unless, if my understanding of your requirement is different with yours.

Comment: is there a way inside Power Apps to create a form which allow users to schedule tasks.. this is my question. either to schedule calls to power automate or schedule a call to code inside Power Apps itself...i hope you got my point.. thanks

Comment: You can use Timer in Power Apps and set the interval. But it's counterproductive for end-user, as they need to open the apps while waiting for the interval to happen/reach. Once closed, then then the interval duration will be completely gone. Is that what you/your end-user want?

Comment: no of course we do not want the App to stay open, and this is my question, if i can write a power App to run schedule jobs similar to scheduled power automate

Comment: Power Automate Scheduler doesn't trigger from Power Apps, it triggers automatically once you set the recurrence. The thing is, once run, then that's your duration. If you set it to run for 5 minutes, it'll run every 5 minutes forever. You can't change the duration dynamically after it's triggered.

Comment: looks like we are not understanding each other, let say i define a timer inside Power App to call the code on schedule basis, then will Power app runs on the background even if no user is accessing it? and what happen if 2 users access the power app,, will we have 2 schedule running..all those cases will not happen if we use Power automate scheduled flow.. so my question can we build power app which mimic the schedule flow on power automate? if you can help, please provide an answer so i and any other user will benefit from..

Comment: See my explanation above. As I mentioned before, you need to use Power Automate if you want to run activities even after the user closes Power Apps.